# Prove this relation

Tags: modular-arithmetic, systems-of-equations

Solve this: $y^2+2=x^3$ or

Prove that  $y^2+2=x^3 => (x,y)=(3,\pm 5)$

I know that it could be obvious to some of you by trial and error but I need a methodical approach.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One observation is that $y$ is even if and only if $x$ is even, but if $y=2m,x=2n$ we have $4m^2+2 = 8n^3$, which happens if and only if $2m^2+1 = 4n^3$, which cannot be since LHS is odd while RHS is even. Hence, neither $x$ nor $y$ can be even...

Comment: @gt6989b Yeah thats a nice observation thanks

Comment: Another one is just as easy: since $y^2 \geq 0$, we must have $x>0$, and the problem is symmetric in $y$, i.e. if $(x,y)$ is a solution, then $(x,-y)$ is a solution as well. Hence, let's look for $y \geq 0$ and it suffices to show that $(3,5)$ is a unique solution.

Comment: @gt6989b Nice one again but how can you say that this suffices to show that (3,5) is a unique solution?

Comment: i am not saying this suffices to show that (3,5) is unique; i said, showing (3.5) is unique suffices to solve the problem, since we now can assume $y>0$...

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/874226). See also [Fermat's sandwich theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FermatsSandwichTheorem.html).