# Fermat's Challenge

Tags: number-theory

This is a question French mathematician Pierre de Fermat posed to the English mathematicians of his time.
"Prove that x=5 and y=3 are the only positive integer values for which $x^2 +2=y^3$."
I have been trying to come up with an answer for days using modular arithmetic to no avail. Any such method would therefore be appreciated as well as other insights.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/874226/proof-that-26-is-the-one-and-only-number-between-square-and-cube

Comment: See e.g. thm 3.4 @ http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/mordelleqn1.pdf