# How can I solve $x^2+2=y^3$ in $\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, diophantine-equations

Prove that $\left \{ (x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}^2:x^2+2=y^3 \right \}\subseteq \left \{ (-5,3),(5,3) \right \}$.

Comment: This is a classic tricky Diophantine equation. I forget how to solve it. My first inclination is to try to use unique factorization in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt {-2}]$

Comment: This is actually an elliptic curve and I believe the standard methods will work here for this question although I'm not posting this as an answer as it may assume too much knowledge on the OP's part

Comment: It's due to Pierre de Fermat  (early 1600's).

Comment: See also [Solve $x^2+2=y^3$ using infinite descent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/677422/solve-x22-y3-using-infinite-descent)

Answer (score 1):

First note that $x$ must be odd.

Then show that in $R=\mathbb Z[\sqrt {-2}]$ that $x+\sqrt{-2}$ and $x-\sqrt{-2}$ are relatively prime. Since $R$ is a unique factorization domain, and all units are cubes, this means the $x+\sqrt{-2}$ is a cube in $R$ (Since their product is a cube.)

Then solve:

$$x+\sqrt{-2}=(a+b\sqrt{-2})^3.$$

Comment: So $x$ has to be odd. If $x$ was even if implies $y$ is even by congruences mod $2$. Then you can let $x=2x_1$ and $y=2y_1$. But then we can cancel a factor of two, and taking the equation mod two again gives a contradiction?

Comment: Or if x and y even, look at both sides modulo $4$

Comment: Ah that makes even more sense!